# Orthogonal mesh yields curved UV Unwrap

Tags: uv

What I've done:

I've imported a .dxf file from AutoCAD, then I've converted the curves (the lines from AutoCAD) into a mesh and I created the walls using extrusions.

All good so far, but the UV Unwrapping seems to be rounded. How can I make an *orthogonal* UV unwrap?
I'm getting the same result using *mark seams*

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have a try to the 'smart UV project', that may meet your need here.

Comment: `U` Unwrap > Cube Projection

Comment: Generally, if seams *were* assigned, and were assigned correctly, then unwrap shouldn't be round. It is round because somewhere it is not unwrapped correctly. In this case you can workaround that by using another options for unwrapping.

Comment: Definitely a seams problem. Either the seams are at the wrong edges or there are no seams assigned at all. I bet it's the second, because there are clearly no seams visible in 3D view.